# Different UIBarButtonItems if Pushed or Modal

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to use different Navigation Bar Button Items for a single View Controller.

The View Controller can be :

- pushed inside a Navigation Controller
- presented modally inside a navigation controller

If it's presented modally, I need a close left bar button to dismiss the modal.

Is there a way to know if the VC is presented modally in order to set a dismiss left bar button accordingly?

Comment: i don't getting your question exactly can you please explain in brief.

Comment: Sure. There's 1 ViewController
If VC is pushed, left bar button item default (back)
If VC is presented, left bar button item = Close
How to change the left bar button item if VC is pushed or modal?

Comment: means you just want to change the bar button title

Comment: And the action: if it's a modal, dismiss it

Comment: k.  i will check it. wait

Comment: Hi you can achieve it by using performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueToFbRegister" sender:self method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by implementing such a method on UIViewController category
and then using this method in viewDidLoad to determine, whether the current controller presented modally or by pushing into navigation controller:

```
- (BOOL)isModal {

    if (self.viewController.navigationController && self.viewController.navigationController.viewControllers.firstObject == self.viewController) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, the second boolean seems to work well on its own, doesn't it? Not familiar with isModalInPopover, what does that check?

Comment: stefano_cdn: You are right, I don't know why it was there (I just copied this from one of my projects). The isModalInPopover does something completely different :) Thanks